# The phone locks it self while it lays with the screen down

Tags: stock-android

It's a very weird issue, after i hold my phone with the screen down it suddenly  locks it self and the screen goes off without any reason. And no i did not pressed the power button while im holding it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only documented example of this I could find was in Sony phones. Turning off Stamina fixed it for [this](https://talk.sonymobile.com/t5/Xperia-Z1-Z1s/Screen-Lock-face-down/td-p/991527) person. They also recommend clearing the cache for Stamina

> - Turn off Stamina mode from Power management.
> - Go to Settings -> Apps -> All -> Stamina mode -> Force stop, Clear data and restart your phone.

Comment: Yes  had Sony phone too.. And stamina turned on. Maybe this is a battery saving mechanism, usually when you put your phone down you don't use it.. Thanks.